# How to extract one or several characters from a Chinese font?

Tags: font-face

I want to use @font-face to import a chinese font into my site. But as we all know chinese fonts are always large.
Since i will only use no more than ten chinese characters one time, i wonder how can i extract several characters from a chinese font?

Tks~

Comment: We need more details to be able to answer this. For starters, what programming language do you want to use to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the FontSquirrel web tools to do this: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

- Expert
- Subsetting: Custom Subsetting
- Single characters

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, reduced my file size from 10mb to 1kb. Absolute game changer.

Answer (score 1):

Other than online uploading solutions, there are also offline editors like [Fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) that can do the same task.

For instance you can look at [this guide](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Create_a_new_TrueType_font_using_a_subset_of_characters_from_an_existing_TrueType_font) for Fontforge which do the same task.

The main reason why this could be preferrable over online solutions are that, other than more customizable subsettings, there are also no file size restrictions in doing the extraction process locally. It is rather common for Chinese fonts especially for those with large collection of glyphs.